# Is possible to import the same configurations and portlets to another portal?

Tags: export, liferay, liferay-6

Best, I have a situation that liked clarifies the following, I have a portal that has 3 sites and other portal 2 with the same number of sites. Each portal is an independent, but now one of the portal sites one will be inserted in the other organization (Portal 2) and I'm not able to do this migration. How do I export and import to the other Portal (2).

thank you

https://www.dropbox.com/s/wsbaov1fqza3qva/Untitled.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If i understand you right, you want the site created in Portal 1 to be migrated to Portal 2. IF so this should be do able through Site Export / Import features.

Go to control panel > Portal 1, site (that needs to be exported)  > manage pages > export tab > select appropriate options (data, permissions, themes, etc.) Make sure which option you select before exporting. Once the file is exported.

Again go to control panel > Portal 2, Site (that needs to be imported) > manage pages > import tab, select the file that was exported and select the same options that were selected while exporting and click on save in import to complete the migration.

Hope this helps !